# Как получить доступ к реализации COM-интерфейса с помощью .NET - клиента?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

Написал COM-библиотеку на C#, которая реализует вывод сообщения в MessageBox.

**ICom.cs**:

```
namespace Adb.Com.Server
{
    [Guid("1347e07e-5271-4abe-931f-894d3853fcb9")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ICom
    {
    }
}
```

**IPrinter.cs**:

```
namespace Adb.Com.Server
{
    [Guid("fc5d2263-80a1-43b0-95b6-e8db03629e06")]
    public interface IPrinter
    {
        void Print(string message);
    }
}
```

**Printer.cs**:

```
namespace Adb.Com.Server
{
    [Guid("1aed58c3-c90e-42cf-a7c5-77d64ae633d2")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICom))]
    public class Printer : IPrinter
    {
        public Printer()
        {
        }

        public void Print(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Your message is {message}");
        }
    }
}
```

И AsseblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Общие сведения об этой сборке предоставляются следующим набором
// набора атрибутов. Измените значения этих атрибутов для изменения сведений,
// связанные со сборкой.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Adb.Com.Server")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Adb.Com.Server")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2020")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("ComExampleKeyFile.snk")]


// Установка значения False для параметра ComVisible делает типы в этой сборке невидимыми
// для компонентов COM. Если необходимо обратиться к типу в этой сборке через
// COM, задайте атрибуту ComVisible значение TRUE для этого типа.
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

// Следующий GUID служит для идентификации библиотеки типов, если этот проект будет видимым для COM
[assembly: Guid("1450b224-ff01-4c73-9a19-7487c48f2e48")]

// Сведения о версии сборки состоят из указанных ниже четырех значений:
//
//      Основной номер версии
//      Дополнительный номер версии
//      Номер сборки
//      Редакция
//
// Можно задать все значения или принять номера сборки и редакции по умолчанию 
// используя "*", как показано ниже:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Зарегистрировал эту библиотеку с помощью `regsvr32`. И дальше возникает вопрос: могу ли я как-то получить доступ к реализации этого интерфейса через .NET - клиентское приложение (не подключая саму dll)? В COM совсем не силен.

Создал `WinForms` приложение. Делаю в проекте `Ссылки -> Добавить ссылку -> COM (tab)`. Там вижу свой COM.

[image: AddReference]

При попытке добавить этот COM-объект выводится ошибка:

> Не удается добавить ссылку на "Adb_Com_Server". Библиотека типов
>   ActiveX "path_to_lib" была экспортирована из сборки .NET и не может
>   быть использована в качестве ссылки. Вместо этого необходимо добавить
>   ссылку на сборку .NET

В общем, пока застрял на этом этапе

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то. Чтобы подключить к .NET другую сборку на .NET, COM Interop вообще не нужен. Какую реальную задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight хочу дернуть интерфейс COM-сервера, который я зарегистрировал в реестре, а именно, метод `void Print(string message);`.

Comment: ^ вот здесь объясняется, почему то, что вы хотите, невозможно. На ваш буквальный вопрос ответ "никак". Смысл COM - взаимодействие .NET c неуправляемым кодом. Сборку на C# вы можете подключить только как сборку на C#, другое невозможно и не нужно.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight сначала хотел сформулировать вопрос `можно ли?`. Спасибо